# phpmyadmin docker site can't be reached

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

Very frustrating error. I hope you can advise me something.

I removed all images, all containers, made system prune with docker.

Then, I run the following command. I know I am not specifying mysql host and password, but who cares, this still should work or show me main page of phpmyadmin where I can login and it should say mysql can't connect.

`sudo docker run --name adminphp1 -d -p 8000:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`.

After running this command, seeing the container list, it shows me the following:

```
389268e87d4b        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh supervisord…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   adminphp1
```

Where does 9000/tcp come from?

After running, `docker logs adminphp1`,  it shows the following:

```
Complete! phpMyAdmin has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/options.py:461: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2019-04-11 15:15:09,745 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2019-04-11 15:15:09,746 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/nginx.ini" during parsing
2019-04-11 15:15:09,746 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/php.ini" during parsing
2019-04-11 15:15:09,756 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-04-11 15:15:09,756 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-04-11 15:15:09,756 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-04-11 15:15:10,760 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 21
2019-04-11 15:15:10,762 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 22
[11-Apr-2019 15:15:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 21
[11-Apr-2019 15:15:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2019-04-11 15:15:11,826 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-04-11 15:15:11,827 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Then I try to access it with website.com:8000 and browser shows me site can't be reached  after thinking out some time.

Just would appreciate anything you can suggest.

Comment: Where are you getting your hostname from? website.com

Comment: It's just an example .

Comment: I matters, die you try accessing it on localhost? or on the ip address on the remote box?

Comment: I did this sudo wget localhost:8000 and it successfully connected to it and downloaded index.html file which contains phpmyadmin's first page code. .so I can't connect from outside. why is that? I have firewall enabled and port 8000 open

Comment: well now you know where to look. Your problem has nothing to do with docker.

Comment: Yes,but I still think something else. I checked by online tool that my ip and port 8000 is open. so why can't  curl connect to website.com:8000?